# Расчет долей по MultiIndex. Ошибка: "cannot handle a non-unique multi-index"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, индексация

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить проблему следующего рода.
Есть `DataFrame` с мультииндексом:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'point': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'sales': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]}, 
                     index=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 3, 3, 3], [1, 2, 3, 3, 1]],
                     names=['country', 'city', 'type']))
```

В идеале хотелось бы посчитать доли продаж в группировке по индексу (т.е. сквозняком через поле point) и добавить в исходный `DataFrame` столбец "new".
Другими словами, надо добавить новый столбец, значения в котором равны отношению продаж точки (sales) к общим продажам по составному индексу (country, city, type)
Конструкция следующего рода:

```
data_gr = data1.groupby(['country', 'city', 'type']).sum()['sales']
data['new'] = data['sales'] / data_gr
```

выдает ошибку - cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!

Как возможно обойти эту проблему?
Спасибо!

Comment: Исправил описание вопроса. Прошу прощения, криво сформулировал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос:

```
In [60]: data['new'] = data['sales'] / data['sales'].groupby(['country', 'city', 'type']).transform('sum')

In [61]: data
Out[61]:
                   point  sales  new
country city type
1       2    1         1      0  NaN
             2         2      1  1.0
        3    3         3      2  0.4
             3         4      3  0.6
             1         5      4  1.0
```

---

**Пояснение:** проще всего показать отличие `df.groupby(...).sum()` и `df.groupby(...).transform('sum')` на примере:

Исходный DataFrame:

```
In [71]: df
Out[71]:
   grp  val
0    1    1
1    2    2
2    2    3
3    3    4
4    3    5
5    3    6
```

`df.groupby(...).sum()` возвращает "редуцированный" DF:

```
In [72]: df.groupby('grp').sum()
Out[72]:
     val
grp
1      1
2      5
3     15
```

`df.groupby(...).transform('sum')` возвращает DF с таким же количеством строк как в исходном DF, в котором сумма группы повторяется для каждой строки из данной группы. Кроме этого, в результирующем дата сете сохраняются оригинальные значения индекса, что позволяет Pandas делать выравнивание по индексу:

```
In [73]: df.groupby('grp').transform('sum')
Out[73]:
   val
0    1
1    5
2    5
3   15
4   15
5   15
```

Comment: Да, то что надо.  Спасибо!